# Function now being called in form submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, function

i'm doing  a React course and at this module i'm learning how to insert data into Firebase database, but i stuck at the current lesson because my code is not inserting data at the database, trying to debug the problem i have found the "cadastrar" function is not being called. Does some one know why it is not inserting data at database?

I didnt get any error, the only problem is I insert data in the input field, then click on the button but it does not insert data into the database.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase'

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor (props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tokenInput: '',
      token: 'Carregando',
      nome: '',
      idade: '',
    };

    this.cadastrar = this.cadastrar.bind(this);

      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    let firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "xxxxxx",
      authDomain: "xxxxx",
      databaseURL: "xxxx",
      projectId: "xxxx",
      storageBucket: "xxxx",
      messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
      appId: "xxxx"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    if(!firebase.apps.length){
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)};

    // Olheiro
    /*
      firebase.database().ref('token').on('value', (snapShot) => {
      let state = this.state;
      state.token = snapShot.val().token;
      this.setState(state);
    });
    */

    firebase.database().ref('token').on('value', (snapshot) => {
      let state = this.state;
      state.token = snapshot.val();
      this.setState(state);
    });

    firebase.database().ref('usuarios').child(1).on('value', (snapShot) => {
      let state = this.state;
      state.nome = snapShot.val().nome;
      state.idade = snapShot.val().idade;
      this.setState(state);
    });

  }

  cadastrar(e){
    firebase.database.ref('token').set(this.state.tokenInput);
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  render(){
    const { token, nome , idade} = this.state;
    return(
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.cadastrar}>
          <input type='text' value={this.state.tokenInput} 
          onChange={(e) => this.setState({tokenInput: e.target.value})} />
          <button type='submit'>Cadastrar1</button>
        </form>

        <h1>Token: {token} </h1>
        <h1>Nome: {nome} </h1>
        <h1>Idade: {idade} </h1>
      </div>
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: any console errors? I think `firebase.database.ref('token')` is supposed to be `firebase.database().ref('token')`

Comment: you are right, the problem was i forgot the () at firebase.database, thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
cadastrar(e){
  firebase.database.ref('token').set(this.state.tokenInput);
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

It might appear that this function isn't being called, but the console is probably showing a TypeError right before reloading the page from the form submission, because `database.ref` is not a function. The code will then stop executing before it gets to the `e.preventDefault()` line. In order to help catch these errors in the future, I'd recommend putting the `preventDefault` call at the top of the handler so that the console output isn't lost.

In order to fix the TypeError, I believe you need to change this to `firebase.database().ref('token')`

Complete function:

```js
cadastrar(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  firebase.database.ref('token').set(this.state.tokenInput);
}
```